# Automatically refresh IOS devices in a team provisioning profile by Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I have some IOS devices week by week to which I must send my apps for testing purposes during development. These devices can't be pluuged to my computer, because they are far away from me and just for this case they won't be taken to my local machine. If plugging would be available, my life would be much easier. But it is not the case.

Now I have to do a lot of annoying things by hand: add it, regenereate it, delete it from local machine, add to new one etc etc.

After adding a device to my devices in Apple developer portal I'd like to have it in XCode without regenerating certificate, delete, download to my local machine. There should be some automatic refresh process.

Before XCode 4.5 there was an option in organizer to refresh it automatically by Xcode.

What about in the current XCode version?

Comment: In Xcode 4.5 same option to refresh is available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Xcode 4.5 same option to refresh is available.

Steps To create Ad hoc Profile which is to be followed before the above process is done.
Check [this](http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/how-to-distribute-ad-hoc-build-with-xcode-4/).

Steps to refresh profile.
1.In developer portal Add device.
2.Update Developer provisioning profile by adding the device to the profile.
3.Open Xcode> Organiser >Devices
4.Delete the old profile

You will find a refresh button at the button click refresh.
Clean the project and Archive it. 
Send it to user, It will work on the new Device.

Answer (score 2):

@TechFanatic's solution didn't work for me.

What did work was for me was:

1. From XCode, select XCode > Preferences.
2. Click the "Accounts" tab.
3. Select your account.
4. Click the "View Details..." button.
5. Click the refresh button in the lower left corner.

This comes from the section ["Refreshing Provisioning Profiles in Xcode"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html) in Apple's documentation.

---

**EDIT:** This no longer works in XCode 7. There is no "refresh" button that I have found anywhere in XCode 7. If you find one, please provide that answer. In the meanwhile, there is a [solution of sorts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32812455/2105930) - you delete and recreate the managed profile.

Specifically, if you are doing an Ad Hoc build:

1. In the [member center](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/profileList.action), delete the "iOS Team Provisioning Profile" for your app. **Do not** delete the "XC Ad Hoc" provisioning profile.
2. In XCode, in the XCode > Preferences menu, in the "Accounts" tab, under "View Details..." for your account, delete the "iOS Team Provisioning Profile" for your app by right-clicking and selecting "Move to Trash".
3. In the "General" tab for your Target, there will be a "Fix Issue" button. Click it.
4. Don't worry that the member center now says that your XC Ad Hoc provisioning profile is now invalid. That will fix itself in a later step.
5. Build your app.
6. Archive your app.
7. Export your app from the "Organizer".
8. Select "Save for Ad Hoc Deployment".
9. XCode will complain that your provisioning profile doesn't match or some such. Click the "Reset" button and then click "Try Again".
10. XCode should continue and create an .ipa file.
11. In the member center, your XC Ad Hoc provisioning profile will show up as active again.

Simple, right?

Comment: Great, I love when they change this stuff.

Comment: Any ideas? It's super annoying to have to go back to manual profiles!

Comment: @WillLarche, updated with the best solution I've found so far.