# Ionic **Build Failed** Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.1'

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

When I am running `ionic run ios --device`
 the build is failing, It was working fine few days ago and now I am getting this error, How to solve it, I have searched the solution but none worked for me.

Below is the error

```
   === BUILD TARGET SoftApp OF PROJECT SoftApp WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===


Check dependencies

Signing for "SoftApp" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.

Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.1'



** BUILD FAILED **



The following build commands failed:
        Check dependencies
(1 failure)

Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/amitabhs/Projects/SoftApp/SoftAppcc/Mobile/SoftAppIonic_cc/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,SoftApp.xcodeproj,ARCHS=armv7 arm64,-target,SoftApp,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphoneos,build,VALID_ARCHS=armv7 arm64,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/amitabhs/Projects/SoftApp/SoftAppcc/Mobile/SoftAppIonic_cc/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/amitabhs/Projects/SoftApp/SoftAppcc/Mobile/SoftAppIonic_cc/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

I have tried un-installing and reinstalling IOS, cordova and ionic, nothing helped

Here is my config:

```
    Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Ionic Framework Version: 1.3.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.20
ios-deploy version: 1.8.6 
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v4.5.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.1 Build version 8B62
```

Comment: can you run the proyect in the phone with xcode?

Comment: @Pablote I tried with xcode, its showing same error

Comment: for the log seems a problem with the keys permisions, maybe in the phone, because talk about the dev team, it's possible the phone it's register in a different dev team. or in the machine is no tregister the dev team. Can you select a dev team in Xcode?

Comment: @Pablote thanks for helping me, you were write, IOS Team provisioning  profile was expired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution,

Actually the problem was with Xcode not ionic, 
I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32729193/refresh-devices-in-team-provisioning-profile-managed-by-xcode-7)

Comment: I have the same issue. I followed the link you are referencing but which solution this you follow?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34666510/2164477  this one solved my problem. can you please up vote it if this works. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Open your `.xcodeproj` file with xcode.

You can find it here: `project_directory/platform/ios/project_name.xcodeproj`

Then select the root file in the project tree on the left.

Now in the `Signing` section make sure `Automatically manage signing` was checked. As a last step you can select a team.