# Error trying to copy IPA from Xcode Devices&Simulators to device

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

I created one IPA via Xcode.

Product -> Archieve -> Distribute Ad Hoc for target real devices `any ios armv7, arm64`
[image]

(so far process was same as always and had it working before with iphone)

The only thing that is changed is that I am using one IPAD instead of old Iphone (sold)

I have registered the IPAD already under `my devices` at https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/devices/list

Then I deleted old Xcode provisioning profiles following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32729193/refresh-devices-in-team-provisioning-profile-managed-by-xcode-7/)

by going to `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning` and deleting all. Then I saw Xcode "fixing" recreating with todays date the new profiles.

Still issue persist, when I drag and drop IPA to device I get error "Unable to install AppName"

[image]

The error message is very short and does not give any detailed information of possible causes.

More details:
Info.plist

```
  <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
  <string>9.0</string>
```

IPAD is already >= 9.0 version as well

The host device that I used to create the IPA has `arm64` architecture, macbook m1 2021

How can I fix this and manage to install the IPA into my ipad and real test the app ?

Comment: Does the spa you have generated is compatible with iOS 9 (iPad version) ?

Comment: Yes minimum version is 9.0 (flutter app compiled for ios) `<key>MinimumOSVersion</key><string>9.0</string>` Funny thing is that I can download and install fine previous app version from apple store in same ipad. Now I am compiling the IPA with new mac device as well (m1 chip arm64, before had old macpro with intel chip) not sure if related

Comment: I just tried on a M1 Mac with no problem. Did you archive for Any iOS device ?

Comment: Yes correct I archive for any ios device https://imgur.com/a/tyJIcSD. Then after successful archieve, distributed ad hoc to create the ipa. Then drag and dropped ipa into the ipad in `devices and simulators` view of xcode. Then it failed to install without any information why

Comment: Did you check on device console log for any other information (it may be hard to find things in all messages)

Comment: How can I do that ? I checked with "logs" option in device and simulators for the ipad but could see hundred thousands of logs from different apps

Comment: On devices and simulator window, select iPad and then "open console". In console click on start message (in the middle of the window) . then try to copy the IPA. After the error, you can pause the console (on top button) and search for any error message about ipa or installation.

Comment: Thanks @PtitXav !!! Very insightful, I saw in logs during install `0x40115000 -[MIBundle isApplicableToOSVersion:error:]: 644: The system version is lower than the minimum OS version specified for bundle at /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.kzZbd1/extracted/Payload/Runner.app. Have 9.3.5; need 10.0` That is a surprise to me as minimum set in info.plist is 9.0

Comment: I had in ios/Podfile `platform :ios, '10.0'` although in info.plist 9.0. This should be reason, I am changing this to 9.0 as well and retrying

Comment: Good you find the source of your problem